# cpu performing better than gpu python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run an openCV program with my GPU. I am using pre-trained models to detect faces on a playing video. The code works fine my question is, how is my CPU performing better than my GPU? Am I missing some attribute that should be defined to use the full potential of the GPU or is it just because the performance of my CPU is better than that of my GPU? Thanks in advacne.

**model download links:**

https://github.com/haroonshakeel/opencv_face_detection

**PC specs:**

OS: Windows 11

GPU: nvidia rtx 3060 mobile

CPU: core i7-12700H

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.video import FPS

class Detector:
    def __init__(self, use_cuda = False):
        self.faceModel = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.prototxt", caffeModel = "models/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")

        if use_cuda:
            self.faceModel.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
            self.faceModel.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
            print("running on GPU")
        else:
            print("running on CPU")

    def processVideo(self, videoName):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName)
        if (cap.isOpened() == False):
            print("error opening video feed")
            return

        (success, self.img) = cap.read()
        (self.height, self.width) = self.img.shape[:2]

        fps = FPS().start()

        while success:
            self.processFrame()
            cv2.namedWindow("Output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) 
            cv2.imshow("Output", self.img)
            cv2.resizeWindow('Output', 900, 900)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord("q"):
                break

            fps.update()
            (success, self.img) = cap.read()

        fps.stop()
        print("Elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
        print("FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def processFrame(self):
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(self.img, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0), swapRB = False, crop = False)    

        self.faceModel.setInput(blob)
        predictions = self.faceModel.forward()

        for i in range(0, predictions.shape[2]):
            if predictions[0, 0, i, 2] > 0.5:
                bbox = predictions[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([self.width, self.height, self.width, self.height])
                (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) = bbox.astype("int")

                cv2.rectangle(self.img, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 2)

detector = Detector(use_cuda = True)
detector.processVideo("test.mp4")
```